# Call to a member function wp_rewrite_rules()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, action

I'm getting an error on my landing page plugin:

```
    2018/05/17 16:25:00 [error] 16590#16590: *61429 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function wp_rewrite_rules() on null in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/wp-includes/rewrite.php:518
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxx/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/xxxxxxxx/includes/functions.php(125): url_to_postid('/go/woocommerce...')
    #1 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxx/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/xxxxxxxxx/includes/functions.php(97): lsx_check_landing_page()
    #2 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxx/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): lsx_landing_page_style_check('/var/www/vhosts...')
```

And this is the code calling that in the plugin:

```
    function lsx_landing_page_style_check( $dir ){
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if( lsx_check_landing_page() ){
    add_filter( 'customize_loaded_components', 'lsx_setup_components', 100 );
    return LSXLDPG_PATH . 'framework';
}
return $dir;
}

function lsx_check_landing_page(){
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if( basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) === 'customize.php' ){      
    parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query );
    if( !empty( $query['url'] ) ){
        $url = $query['url'];
    }
    // if saving
}
if( !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'customize_save' ){
    $url = wp_get_referer();
    $parsed = parse_url( $url );
    if( 'customize.php' == basename( $parsed['path'] ) && !empty( $parsed['query'] ) ){
        $query = urldecode( $parsed['query'] );
        parse_str( $query, $ref );
        if( !empty( $ref['url'] ) ){
            $url = $ref['url'];
        }
    }
}   
if( false !== strpos( $url, '/go/' ) ){
    $landing_page = url_to_postid( $url );
    if( !empty( $landing_page ) ){
        return $landing_page;
    }
    return true;
}   
return false;
}
```

I'm loading all this in my main plugin file with add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function(){ ....

But I don't know why is causing these issues. Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should get from `url_to_postid()` in your code. Maybe the var `$url` is empty or wrong. This function checks that you use permalinks and use the function `wp_rewrite_rules()`.

As hint, you should use [xDebug](https://xdebug.org/) to get better error messages include a stacktrace so that you see the source of the error, not only the result of the error.